# Finite fiber of scheme morphism is zero-dimensional?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, abstract-algebra

Let $X$ and $Y$ be locally Noetherian schemes and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be an étale morphism of finite type. Let $x\in X$ and $y=f(x)$. I would like to know why the fiber $X_y$ is a zero-dimensional scheme. This is statement without justification in Liu's *Algebraic Geometry*. By a prior result, we know that $X_y$ is finite and reduced when the hypothesis above hold. This seems to intuitively be enough to insure it is zero-dimensional (compare to manifolds consisting of a finite number of points, for example), but I don't know how to prove it using material in Liu.

I've pieced together a proof of this using theorems in the Stacks project that I haven't seen in Liu, but Liu passes over it in a sentence without explanation. Is there an easy way to see it is true?

Comment: What's your definition of étale morphism? In any case, one can show that the fibre $X_y$ is _discrete_ as a topological space, and so must be zero-dimensional (because there are no interesting irreducible sets!).

Comment: @ZhenLin Unramified and flat. Is there an easy way to see $X_y$ is discrete?

Answer (score 4):

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a morphism locally of finite presentation.

1. $f : X \to Y$ is unramified if and only if all its fibres are unramified, so we may assume $Y = \operatorname{Spec} k$.
2. $f : X \to \operatorname{Spec} k$ is unramified if and only if $X$ is a disjoint union of affine schemes of the form $\operatorname{Spec} K$ where $K$ is a finite separable field extension of $k$.
3. So if $f : X \to \operatorname{Spec} k$ is unramified, then $X$ is discrete as a topological space.

To see (2), one may also assume $X$ is affine. Then the problem is reduced to commutative algebra – more precisely, to the structure theorem for artinian rings.

Comment: This is essentially what I found via the Stacks project. Liu requires the stronger hypothesis that the map be of finite type (and étale), which leads me to believe a simpler argument may work. Do you know if the proof can be simplified using these stronger hypotheses?

Comment: The question is local on the domain and the codomain, and both are locally noetherian, so there's no practical difference between "locally of finite presentation" and "of finite type".